# Decision Tree produces different outputs

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, decision-tree

I am currently using decision trees (using Scikit Learn) to predict certain values. The problem I'm facing is that the output of the algorithm is not consistent. Is this a property of Decision Trees? On multiple runs (with no change to data/algorithm) I get different results.

I used Scikit's Decision Tree Class without changing anything to start with

```
svr = DecisionTreeRegressor()
```

Then, to remove any 'randomness', I changed it to

```
svr = DecisionTreeRegressor(splitter='best', random_state=None)
```

What is causing the different results? And how do I prevent them?

Two of the results being (plotted for simplicity) 
Red is DTR results. Blue is the test set.

[image: Image One]

[image: Image Two]

Comment: Any Training/Test set split? Actually what is the red/blue curve?

Comment: @CAFEBABE Sorry, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html):

> **random_state** : int, RandomState instance or None, optional
>   (default=None)
>
> If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number 
>    generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number
>   generator; If None, the random number generator is the RandomState
>   instance used by np.random.

For `None` it'll use `np.random` which is also random. To make reproducible example you need to specify `int` number in `random_state`. For example:

```
svr = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
```

For your case you doing:

```
svr = DecisionTreeRegressor(splitter='best', random_state=None)
```

Which is the same behaviour for `random_state` as by default.

Comment: Thank you. That fixes it. If I could trouble you some more, where can I find more information about random state and how it affects DTs (apart from Numpy docs)?

Comment: @user3653438 I think that `random_state` is the same as [`np.random.RandomState`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html)

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) shows the following:

*random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional (default=None)
If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator
If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator
If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random.*

Perhaps numpy is generating a new RandomState each time you call DecisionTreeRegressor ?

Comment: Thank you that is where the problem was.